# Error “This is not a structured storage file” when load .msg file

Tags: outlook, aspose, msg

I use Aspose.Email for view content of .msg file and this is my code:

```
Dim msg As MapiMessage = MapiMessage.FromFile(“D:\Test\md50000003583.msg”)
```

However, it shows the following error:

> “This is not a structured storage file”

Here's the  [link to my .msg file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y4bySYYtqh8zEfWKVS1ib5BAs3hORHwU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

The file you have is the EML (MIME) file - not an MSG file. See [Difference between a .msg file and a .eml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229591/difference-between-a-msg-file-and-a-eml-file/16230261#16230261) for the explanation of the difference between the two.

Comment: sorry, i'm using MDaemon for email server and all emails have file extension is *.msg, not eml

Comment: The extension does not matter. What matters is what is inside. Renaming a file with an EML extension to MSG does not make it a true MSG file. Open both files in Notepad to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the file is corrupt as it can't be opened by MS Outlook or MFCMapi as well. We have already shared our findings with you in Aspose.Email forum as well. If your message is of EML format, use MailMessage to load the EML file.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.